# Unexpected behaviour from Physics and Collision Detection

Tags: c++, if-statement, logic, collision-detection, physics

I have worked on this problem for months and my current solution still does not work. I am working on simple bounding box collision between a square pawn and a vector of square tiles.

In this current method the player will collide correctly on the bottom, left and right but not on top. I do not understand why.

This is the physics function, which deals with motion:

```
void loop(Pawn *pawn) {

    int currentFPS = fps->getFPS();

    //friction
    if (pawn->velX > 0.0) {
        pawn->velX *= 0.91f;
    }
    if (pawn->velY > 0) {
        pawn->velY *= 0.91f;
    }
    if (pawn->velX < 0) {
        pawn->velX *= 0.91f;
    }
    if (pawn->velY < 0) {
        pawn->velY *= 0.91f;
    }

    //gravity
    pawn->velY += gravity;

    //motion
    pawn->posY += pawn->velY; //move along the horizontal axis
    pawn->posX += pawn->velX; //move along the vertical axis

    //handle collision
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++) {
        collide(pawn, getLevelCollision[i]);
    }

}
```

This is the collision function, which checks for collision and then corrects the pawn position based on which edge is intersecting the colliding rectangle:

```
void collide(Pawn *pawn, SDL_Rect rect2) {

    bool collide = false;

    //create positions of rect1
    float rect1Top = pawn->posY;
    float rect1Bottom = rect1Top + pawn->position.h;
    float rect1Left = pawn->posX;
    float rect1Right = rect1Left + pawn->position.w;

    //create position of rect2
    float rect2Top = rect2.y;
    float rect2Bottom = rect2.y + rect2.h;
    float rect2Left = rect2.x;
    float rect2Right = rect2.x + rect2.w;



    //if the bottom edge of rect1 intersects rect2 vertically
    if (rect1Bottom > rect2Top && rect1Bottom < rect2Bottom) {
        //if rect1 and rect2 are on top of each other
        if (rect1Right > rect2Left && rect1Right < rect2Right || rect1Left < rect2Right && rect1Left > rect2Left) {
            pawn->posY = rect2Top - pawn->position.h;

            rect1Top = pawn->posY;
            rect1Top = pawn->position.h;
        }
    }

    //if the left edge of rect1 intersects rect2 horizontally
    else if (rect1Left < rect2Right && rect1Left > rect2Left) {
        //if rect1 and rect2 are on top of each other
        if (rect1Top < rect2Bottom && rect1Top > rect2Top || rect1Bottom > rect2Top && rect1Bottom < rect2Bottom) {
            pawn->posX = rect2Right;

            rect1Left = pawn->posX;
            rect1Right = rect1Left + pawn->position.w;
        }
    }

    //if the right edge of rect1 intersects rect2 horizontally
    else if (rect1Right > rect2Left && rect1Right < rect2Right) {
        //if rect1 and rect2 are on top of each other
        if (rect1Top < rect2Bottom && rect1Top > rect2Top || rect1Bottom > rect2Top && rect1Bottom < rect2Bottom) {
            pawn->posX = rect2Left - pawn->position.w;

            rect1Left = pawn->posX;
            rect1Right = rect1Left + pawn->position.w;
        }
    }

    //if the top edge of rect1 intersects rect2 vertically
    if (rect1Top < rect2Bottom && rect1Top > rect2Top) {
        //if rect1 and rect2 are on top of each other
        if (rect1Right > rect2Left && rect1Right < rect2Right || rect1Left < rect2Right && rect1Left > rect2Left) {
            pawn->posY = rect2Bottom;

            rect1Top = pawn->posY;
            rect1Top = rect1Top + pawn->position.h;
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot understand why the top edge of the pawn does not collide as every possible iteration of if / else if has been tried as well as rearranging the order of the if statements.

I am desperate for insight on this problem as well as a new set of eyes to see what I am clearly not able to.

Comment: What is `getLevelCollision`?

Comment: Also, a side note: you could simplify the `// friction` part of `loop()` to: `pawn->velX *= 0.91f; pawn->velY *= 0.91f;`. The thing is, that `velX` and `velY` get multiplied by `0.91f`, unless they are zero. But if they *are* zero, then multiplying them by `0.91f` will leave them zero...

Comment: getLevelCollision is a vector of SDL_Rects that denote tiles. These are loaded into the program from a level image file.

Comment: Can you give us the values of the members of `pawn` and `rect2` which ought to produce a collision but don't?